# How to check conditions of result

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I'm trying to create a stored procedure, that has to check the zone column and based on that select/output a string.

there are 5 incidents (zones): 1-5.
I'm using 1 IN parameter from my php:

```
select zone 
from customer
where customerId = in_customerId;
```

But from here were do I return one of the 5 incidents?
I'm pretty sure I have to use the if condition but how?

```
1 should be equal to monday
2 should be equal to tuesday
3 should be equal to wednesday
4 should be equal to thursday
5 should be equal to friday
```

Comment: MySQL supports if/then conditions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: Where are you using the `IN()` parameter?

Comment: in_customerId is my parameter?

Comment: in_customerId looks like a field in the customer table. Not an IN() clasue https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: ah so IN(in_customerId)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `case` to return different result. Something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE zone
        WHEN 1 THEN 'monday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'tuesday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'wednesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'thursday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'friday'
        ELSE 'unknown'
    END
FROM customer
WHERE customerId = in_customerId;
```

See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html) for more info